# How do I reconfigure a Mt. Gox Yubikey?

Tags: security, mtgox, data-security, security-key

After following [the instructions here](http://forum.yubico.com/files/VIPunlockGuide.pdf), which suggested I use [`ykpers`](http://yubico.github.io/yubikey-personalization/) or the [gui version](http://yubico.github.io/yubikey-personalization-gui/), I discovered the Mt. Gox Yubikey is protected by a "configuration protection access code."

From [the manual](http://static.yubico.com/var/uploads/pdfs/YubiKey_manual-2.2.pdf):

> **Protection of the key and configuration data**
>
> Given the symmetric nature of the AES encryption algorithm, the
>   security of the Yubikey relies that the AES key is logically and
>   physically protected both in the key and in the server that verifies
>   the OTP.
>
> The configuration data is updated via a configuration API, accessible
>   via the USB interface. To prevent unauthorized update, the
>   configuration can be protected by a 48-bit access code. If used, an
>   exhaustive search of all combinations would typically take some
>   100,000 years to perform. Furthermore, the Yubikey configuration data
>   is write-only, i.e. configuration data and the key can only be written
>   but not be read. This means that unauthorized update of the
>   configuration is an act of sabotage rather than a security threat.
>
> The configuration data is stored in a non-volatile storage integral to
>   the microcontroller. A potential attack is to physically probe the
>   silicon or analyze the hardware behavior to potentially gain full or
>   partial knowledge of the stored secrets. However, such an attack would
>   require a complete break-up of the Yubikey, involving dissolving the
>   microcontroller chip encapsulation. Furthermore, very advanced
>   equipment is needed to probe the chip internals. Given the effort and
>   costs involved for such an attack, this is not considered a threat
>   given that just a single device will be broken.

Yubikey wrote me:

> In case, if you have forgotten the configuration protection code or do
>   not find it in the log file, then you can not reconfigure the YubiKey
>   slot again. This functionality is implemented to strengthen the
>   security.

Also, he wrote:

> In the context of [the manual](http://static.yubico.com/var/uploads/pdfs/YubiKey_manual-2.2.pdf), an "unauthorized update of the
>   configuration" would be changing the configuration settings on an
>   unprotected YubiKey. Since you already have an access code in place,
>   you cannot preform such an update.

**But it should still be possible to "sabotage" a Mt. Gox Yubikey, no? If not, why? If so, how?**

thanks

<strike>What is also strange is that when I try to create an account at [forum.yubico.com](http://forum.yubico.com) or test my Yubikey at [demo.yubico.com](http://demo.yubico.com), they reject my OTP. Yubico Forum's registration says my OTP can't contain non alphanumeric characters, and it sometimes contains periods.</strike> [Update: this ended up being because I was using Dvorak keyboard layout for the Yubikey. I've changed it, and now my OTPs work on these sites.]

UPDATE #2: I found this: https://github.com/nezza/yubicrack
But there has to be a quicker way than doing a brute-force search of the code. I really wonder why it is so hard to flash a Yubikey? Is it so that others can't render it effectively "lost" or "stolen"?

Comment: Since Mt. Gox's bankruptcy the unlock codes were leaked, see [What is Mt. Gox's YubiKeys' "configuration protection access code"?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29702/what-is-mt-goxs-yubikeys-configuration-protection-access-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in [a newer, strongly related question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/29702/1137): You can now get the leaked keys from https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=631044.0

Answer (score 1):

Mt. Gox locks their Yubikeys with an access code. You cannot reprogram them without the code. If you're willing to wait a few months, you can [brute force](https://github.com/nezza/yubicrack) it.

Comment: And they wouldn't release the access code because it would render the Yubikey useless with Mt. Gox? Why did they opt to make their Yubikeys exclusive for Mt. Gox?

Comment: @Geremia: Doing it this way eliminates [a number of potential vulnerabilities](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/7171/85).

Comment: Do you know if Mt. Gox would release or has released the access code, now that they're belly-up? If so, we could reprogram the YubiKeys they sent us with a different access code and use them for other purposes. The YubiKey they sent me is just collecting dust…