# What is Mt. Gox's YubiKeys' "configuration protection access code"?

Tags: security, mtgox, authentication

Does anyone know if Mt. Gox, now that they're bankrupt, has released their YubiKey's "configuration protection access code" (cf. [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/11751/4334))? If so, we could reprogram the free YubiKeys they sent us and use them for other purposes.

Does anyone know their contact information?

thanks

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14809/6733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the unlock codes were leaked:
>
> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=631044

([source](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=709921.msg8023282#msg8023282))